# No default engine was specified and no extension was provided express

Tags: javascript, html, express, static

I'm trying to only use html and render pages from my express server. I keep getting the error

```
No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

I have specified the dirname in app.js and I am telling the server to render by using the dirname in my router. I'm not really sure what's holding me up? Can someone provide some insight?

app.js ( I have removed import statements that aren't relevant)

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  //setting static file directory
//Store all HTML files in view folder.

module.exports = app;
```

here's my index router where I am calling render on the pages

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('main', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET styles page. */
router.get('/style', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('styles', { title: 'styles' });
});

/* GET styles page. */
router.get('/style',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/style.html'));
});





module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a renderer like Handlebars, you can't call `res.render` as far as I know. If you are serving static views you don't need a renderer anyways, you just specify the folder where the static files are located at.

This means after you have specified your static folder, you will be able to access the files by having their filename in the route. [Express' documentation on static files.](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express) You don't need routes to send the files.

### Example

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-express-server-ttcxw?file=/src/index.js:0-498)

```
src
|- view
|  |- hello.html
|- index.js
```

#### index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
//create a server object:
const app = express();

//Serve all files inside the view directory, path relative to where you started node
app.use(express.static("src/view/"));

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("server running on 8080");
}); //the server object listens on port 8080

module.exports = app;
```

You will now see `hello.html` on the `/hello.html` route. Any other file will also be visible under its name.

Comment: thanks this helped me out a lot! I was looking at a different tutorial and kinda got lost for a bit.